# Nesting resources in .NET Core 2.2 Web API

Tags: c#, rest

Sorry for being such a newbie on this subject but:
I have a WEB API project and I am trying to use REST

I have two classes Employee and Department. 
I have a controller for each class

On their own, I can view the classes

```
https://localhost:44309/api/employees/3 gives me the desired info of
```

[{"id":3,"department":null,"departmentID":1,"firstName":"Chris","lastName":"Dunlop","jobTitle":"Software Developer","mailingAddress":"3456 6th Street SW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5"}]

and

```
https://localhost:44309/api/departments/3 gives me the desired info of
```

[{"id":3,"name":"HR","address":"789 10th Street SW Calgary Alberta"}]

Now... What I am trying to do is the following:

```
https://localhost:44309/api/employees/department/3
```

I get localhost page cannot be found.

```
public class Employee
    {
        #region Properties

        public int ID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        public string MailingAddress { get; set; }

        #endregion Properties
    }

public class Department
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my Departments Controller

```
{
    [Route("api/Departments")]
    [ApiController]
    public class DepartmentsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();

        // GET: api/Departments
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Department> GetAll()
        {
            departments.Add(new Department { ID = 1, Name = "Application Development", Address = "123 4th Street NW Calgary Alberta" });
            departments.Add(new Department { ID = 2, Name = "Management", Address = "456 7th Street NE Calgary Alberta" });
            departments.Add(new Department { ID = 3, Name = "HR", Address = "789 10th Street SW Calgary Alberta" });

            return departments;            
        }

        // GET api/Departments/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Department> Get(int id)
        {
            GetAll();
            return departments.Where(departments => departments.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my Employees controller

```
{
    [Route("api/Employees")]
    [ApiController]

    public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        // GET: api/Employees
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll()
        {
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 1, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "1234 4th Avenue NW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 2, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "2345 5th Street NE Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 3, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "3456 6th Street SW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });

            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 4, DepartmentID = 2, FirstName = "Vince", LastName = "O'Gorman", JobTitle = "Development Supervisor", MailingAddress = "1201 49th Street NE Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 5, DepartmentID = 3, FirstName = "Tracey", LastName = "Jarvis", JobTitle = "HR Manager", MailingAddress = "1301 69th Street SW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });

            return employees;
        }

        // GET api/Employees/1
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int id)
        {
            GetAll();
            return employees.Where(Employee => Employee.ID == id);
        }

        // GET api/Employees/Department/1
        [HttpGet("int/{deptid}")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get2(int deptId)
        {
            GetAll();
            return employees.Where(Employee => Employee.DepartmentID == deptId);            
        }
    }


}
```

In the Employee controller you can see that I am trying to get a second HTTPGET to get the department. What am I missing here. I have never done this before and and have too many hours to continue to spin my wheels on it. Can anyone help me get my third type of request to work? (ie:

```
https://localhost:44309/api/employees/department/3)
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route is wrong. Please check:

```
{
    [Route("api/Employees")]
    [ApiController]

    public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        // GET: api/Employees
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAll()
        {
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 1, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "1234 4th Avenue NW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 2, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "2345 5th Street NE Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 3, DepartmentID = 1, FirstName = "Chris", LastName = "Dunlop", JobTitle = "Software Developer", MailingAddress = "3456 6th Street SW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });

            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 4, DepartmentID = 2, FirstName = "Vince", LastName = "O'Gorman", JobTitle = "Development Supervisor", MailingAddress = "1201 49th Street NE Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { ID = 5, DepartmentID = 3, FirstName = "Tracey", LastName = "Jarvis", JobTitle = "HR Manager", MailingAddress = "1301 69th Street SW Calgary Alberta T1Y 6R5" });

            return employees;
        }

        // GET api/Employees/1
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int id)
        {
            GetAll();
            return employees.Where(Employee => Employee.ID == id);
        }

        // GET api/Employees/Department/1
        [HttpGet("department/{deptid}")]. // <-- HERE
        public IEnumerable<Employee> GetByDepartmentId(int deptId)
        {
            GetAll();
            return employees.Where(Employee => Employee.DepartmentID == deptId);            
        }
    }
}
```